# Show that $h$ has a pole of order $j$ at $a \in \Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

**Information**: This is a proof verification question, where the OP needs both development how to write formally and also needs verification whether the proof is correct in terms of the logic.

**Question**: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open and connected, $h: \Omega \setminus {a} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $ a \in \mathbb{C}$, is of the form

$h(z) = \frac{a_j}{(z-a)^j} + ... + \frac{a_1}{z-a} + \phi(z)$, where $\phi : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, $ j \in \mathbb{N}$, and ${a_1},...,{a_j} \in \mathbb{C}$ with ${a_j} \neq 0$. Show that h has a pole of order $j$ at $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

**Proof**: We need to show two things for the proof. First, $\lim_{z\to a} \lvert h(z) \rvert = \infty$. And we also show, there exists a unique function $g : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $g(a) \neq 0$ s.t. $h(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^j}$.

**Showing the limit**: As $z \rightarrow a$, the principal part goes to infinity. Since every $a_j$ is some coefficient, and denominators force the value to infinity, and also $\phi(z)$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ which implies that it is bounded near $a$, we know that limit goes to infinity.

**Finding g**: Consider $g(z) = (z-a)^jh(z)$. Since both $(z-a)^j$ and $h(z)$ are holomorphic, simply $g(z)$ is holomorphic too. Also, $g(a) \neq 0$. Therefore, we can write $h(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^j}$. This $j$ is called the order of pole, by definition.

Comment: Is $h(z)$ holomorphic at $z=a$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring That is not given, but I think we can handle that with removable singularity?

Comment: Actually, it is given.  As long as $j > 0$, it's not holomorphic at $z=a$ (it's a pole), so the "Since both $(z-a)^j$ and $h(z)$ are holomorphic, [...]" is false.  You need to actually look at $g(z)$ more closely to see why it's holomorphic at $a \in \Omega$.

Comment: Hmm, then we should first define $g: \Omega \setminus a \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and then we should show why we can add $a$ to the domain. I see, but how can I do that? Using removable singularity?

Comment: Better is to literally write out what $g(z)$ is by using the form of $h(z)$ given.  That is, write out $g(z)$ in terms of the $a_i$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Oh, then $g(a) \neq 0$, it is actually equal to $a_j$. So that no singularity at $a \in \Omega$ ? I believe this is the answer!

Comment: @BrianMoehring One final question, we say g is bounded near a because it is holomorphic on $\Omega$ right? I wrote it but I felt like I wrote it from memorization, then thinking about it made me confused.

Comment: @amdryzen7000 Yes - any holomorphic function is continuous, and continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. In $\Bbb C$, compact iff closed and bounded. Now choose your favorite compact set around $a$, contained in $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comments on formal writing and the proof:*

1. Question: You should mention that $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$ is open and $a\in \Omega$.
2. Proof: We want $g$ to be holomorphic - just any function will not do.
3. Proof 2: Isn't $\lim_{z\to a} |h(z)| = \infty$ unnecessary? If you find the required holomorphic function $g: \Omega\to \Bbb C$ with $g(a) \ne 0$ such that $h(z) = g(z)/(z-a)^j$, doesn't $\lim_{z\to a} |h(z)| = \infty$ follow from the boundedness of $g$ on some compact set containing $a$?
4. Showing the limit: "since every $a_j$ is some coefficient" can be replaced by something along the lines of "since every $a_j \in \Bbb C$ is fixed, the $a_j$'s are bounded" - since that's what you really use for the limit.

Comment: Hm, thank you. But it is not necessary, because actually this is the definition of pole at a. Function must go infinity while $z \rightarrow a$.

Comment: @amdryzen7000 Not sure if you understood my comment - my point is that there's no need to check the first condition about limits, it follows automatically from the existence of $g$.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you!